# Why SafeAreaView Background Not Working in React Native?

Tags: react-native, safeareaview

In my app SafeareaView Not Working. And I can to change Background Color
Check This Image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

Just Add `<StatusBar backgroundColor="red" />`

Answer (score 0):

`Statusbar` is not covered in the `SafeAreaView`. StatusBar is different component.

The purpose of `SafeAreaView` is to render content within the safe area boundaries of a device. It is currently only applicable to iOS devices with iOS version 11 or later.

`SafeAreaView` reflect the portion of the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and other ancestor views.

If you want to change the StatusBar color for android.

1. First import the StatusBar component from react native.

   > import { StatusBar} from 'react-native';
2. Use the StatusBar component like this.

   > <StatusBar animated={true} backgroundColor="red"/>

Read more about StatusBar React Native documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.68/statusbar)

Comment: Thanks for Your ans I am try to change color in status bar color. now its change.